# How to unit test the setters with OnPropertyChanged(); in it?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mvvm, mstest

I'm testing a view model with getters and setters(). it's base class is ObservableObject and has OnPropertyChanged() in setter. I don't know how to test the setter to verify the value is set and propertychanged event is raised. Could you show me a example how to?

```cs
public class ViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    private Connection _connection;
       
    public string ConnectionName { get { return _connection.ConnectionName; } set { _connection.ConnectionName = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } }
          
    public ViewModel(Connection connection)
    {
        _connection = connection;
    }
}
```

Here is how I test a ViewModel derived from INotifyPropertyChanged.

```cs
class GroupViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public GroupViewModel()
    {        
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Group> _groupList;

    public ObservableCollection<Group> GroupList
    {
        get { return _groupList; }

        set
        {
            _groupList = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("GroupList");
        }
    }

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

```cs
public class GroupViewModelTests
{
    [TestMethod()]
    public void TestGroupList()
    {
        List<Group> listOfGroups = new List<Group>();
        Group Group = new Group();
        listOfGroups.Add(Group);

        bool didFire = false;
        GroupViewModel _viewModel = new GroupViewModel();
        ObservableCollection<Group> _groupList = new ObservableCollection<Group>(listOfGroups);

        _viewModel.PropertyChanged += (s, e) =>
        {
            didFire = true;
            Assert.AreEqual("GroupList", e.PropertyName);
            Assert.AreEqual(true, _viewModel.GroupList.Equals(_groupList));
        };

        _viewModel.GroupList = _groupList;
        Assert.IsTrue(didFire);
    }
}
```

Comment: You showed us a code example with a unit test for your proeprty. What exactly is the proplem with that test?

Comment: I put that unit test code example to show what kind of test I want (verify the value is set and the propertychanged event is raised for the correct property, I like to do the same test for the setters with OnPropertyChanged() in it , but I don't know how to.

Comment: If the property you are testing really is as simple as the code example, this Software Engineering question might be worth a read: [Where is the line between unit testing application logic and distrusting language constructs?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/322909/118878)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to use a unit test library such as [`FluentAssertions`](https://fluentassertions.com/) which [supports monitoring event raising](https://fluentassertions.com/eventmonitoring/).

For example, using `FluentAssertions` it's as easy as this:

```
// ARRANGE

var subject          = new GroupViewModel();
var monitoredSubject = subject.Monitor();
var listOfGroups     = new List<Group>() { new() };
var groupList        = new ObservableCollection<Group>(listOfGroups);

// ACT

subject.GroupList = groupList;

// ASSERT

subject.GroupList.Should().Equal(groupList);

monitoredSubject.Should()
    .Raise("PropertyChanged")
    .WithSender(subject)
    .WithArgs<PropertyChangedEventArgs>(args => 
        args.PropertyName == nameof(GroupViewModel.GroupList));
```

Note that `FluentAssertions` is available as a NuGet package.

Answer (score 2):

The basic method is to do just as you are doing. Add an event handler to the event and check that it has been called, and called with the correct argument.

However, my preference is to add a helper method when setting the object:

```
public ObservableCollection<Group> GroupList
{
    get => _groupList
    set => Set(ref _groupList, value);
}
...

private void Set<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string caller = "")
{
     if (!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value))
     {
           field = value;
           PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(caller));
     }
}
```

This moves just about all the complicated logic to a common method that can be reused. The equality-part is optional.

In my opinion there is fairly little value in unit testing code like this. Just looking at the property to tell that it will raise PropertyChanged if you are familiar with this pattern. Unit testing is also not sufficient, you will need to test the actual UI to make sure all the bindings work, and if you are doing manual testing anyway the value of the unit tests is lower. Keep in mind unit tests are supposed to save time. If you write to many unit tests you will likely spend more time than you will save. If you write to detailed unit tests you risk writing fragile tests that will need to be updated for even minor, valid changes.

Comment: `In my opinion there is fairly little value in unit testing code like this`. I disagree with this particular case. I've seen bugs more than once where someone has cut and paste code and forgotten to update the property name passed to `NotifyPropertyChanged()`. A unit test would at least increase the chances of noticing such a bug.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Well, if you use the example I posted you will at least avoid *that* specific issue, since the property name is injected by the compiler. I'm not saying there is *no* value to such a test.  And if you still find that the cost/benefit is positive, great, continue writing those tests! But the cost/benefit ratio will not be the same for all developers, and the "you must have 100% test coverage, otherwise you are a poor developer" mantra *some* espouse is just harmful.